# How does winmain 'return two values'?

Tags: c++, winapi

I wanted to start learning the windows api, so I looked at some tutorials, and instantly I noticed that the main function appeared to return multiple values.

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow);
```

What does all of this mean? Shouldn't it be `int WinMain` or `WINAPI WinMain` but not both?

Comment: @Claudiu oh im new here i didnt know questions were actually saved that long

Comment: @Claudiu actually those answers on that question didn't answer what i was asking

Comment: It's just a macro. It's equivalent to `int __stdcall WinMain(...`. It's a compiler-specific extension, not a standard. The answer to your question is that it doesn't return two values, since `WINAPI` isn't a return value.

Answer (score 5):

[`WINAPI`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a macro that expands to `__stdcall`. It specifies the calling convention, not the return type.  The return type is still 'int'

Comment: Im still confused with the placement of it

Comment: Just regard it as a non-standard C++ extension for targeting Windows platforms. Microsoft could have placed it anywhere they liked so long as it didn't completely ruin standard C++ grammar.

Comment: @Bathsheba ok so i dont have to worry about that wierd syntax :)

Comment: Bathsheba is correct about the placement - it's just compiler convention. I'd disagree slightly about the 'daft'.  Any function caller and callee have to agree on how arguments are passed.  The most general way -`cdecl` - is not always the fastest way, especially on the old intel segmented architectures.  So the microsoft API supported some faster alternatives. See [Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/02/47184.aspx)  for some background.

Answer (score 0):

In order for C++ compilers to target Windows efficiently, some extensions to standard C++ were made.

One of them is `WINAPI`, which in Win32, gets expanded to `__stdcall`. That's a non-standard compiler directive that tells the compiler to pass arguments from left to right (for compatibility with VBA etc). Technically, it's called a *calling convention*.

Hence it has nothing to do with the return type and therefore you still need to write an explicit return type.

(Note that in Win64, Microsoft dispense with `__stdcall` entirely so WINAPI is defined to blank).

Comment: Upvote by Bill Gates.

Comment: I didn't think __stdcall was defined to anything other than blank...

Comment: Ooh, so *appalling* that you got down-voted. Joking aside, (although it was not me), I don't appreciate answers that show such exaggerated bias.

Comment: With the SDK 8.1 I have much less respect for Microsoft's published APIs.